# Elixir file stream reuse/fork

Tags: elixir

I have an extremely large csv file with dates and integers.  I need to create an Ecto record for each file record.  The problem is, the integers need to be manipulated based on the minimum time difference between the dates of neighboring records.  I have been trying to process the stream up to a point, binding to a variable, then using that for two different calculations.  But the second calculation gets an empty stream.  It appears that any access to the stream, removes whatever I got.  Is there some way to reuse/fork/clone/dup/something a stream?  I know RX streams has this concept.  I tried thinking of some way to do this in a single chain, but came up empty.  Here is basically the flow I was trying:

```
def do_something(path) do
  {:ok, file} = File.open(path)
  stream = file
  |> IO.stream(:line)
  |> Stream.map(&String.split(&1, ","))

  dates = stream_to_dates(stream) # stream
  factor = dates_to_factor(dates) # float
  values = stream_to_values(stream, factor) # stream

  Stream.zip(dates, values)
end
```

I am able to compute the dates, and then the factor, but right after that, the stream and dates are both empty streams, thus the values is empty, thus the zip is empty...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Stream.transform` to create a stream of pairs from a given stream:

```
def pairs(stream) do
  Stream.transform(stream, nil, fn(x, last) ->
    # The first element is the list of values to return at this point,
    # the second one is the new accumulator
    {[{last, x}], x}
  end)
  # Drop the first pair of {nil, something}
  |> Stream.drop(1)
end
```

Then:

```
iex(1)> 1..1000 |> Stream2.pairs |> Enum.take(5)
[{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}]
```

You should then be able to use pair after `|> Stream.map(&String.split(&1, ","))` to obtain pairs of neighboring records. If you need bigger chunks the function can be generalized.